# WPQuery calling specific posts problem

Tags: wp-query, pages

When I change the order of the posts in the array, the order they appear on the page stays the same. If I delete pages from the array they also disappear.

Trying to change order they are displayed but it ain't happening. Any ideas?

```
<?php
            $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post__in' => array(69,67,59)
            );                  
            $my_tile_pages = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ($my_tile_pages -> have_posts()) : $my_tile_pages -> the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="box vertical-esp">

                    <div class="innerBox" style="background: url(<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>) no-repeat; background-position: 50%; background-size: cover;">
                        <div class="titleBox">
                            <article>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                            </article><!-- #post-## -->
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- .innerBox -->
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; 
            wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the [`order` and `orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) arguments with your query, the results will be ordered ascending by date, no matter what order you put the pages in with `post__in`. If you have an order in mind that isn't covered by one of the regular `orderby` arguments, you'll have to define a metavalue on the pages to store the desired order.